# How to transform a non-observable to an observable properly?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a non-observable and I want it to transform into an observable so I can get direct updates of images instead of refreshing the page to get results but I get the following error:

```sh
Type 'EntityImage[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<EntityImage[]>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 5 more.ts(2740)
```

.html

```html
<div *ngFor="let image of (images$ | async); let i = index;">
  <img src="{{image.url}}" />
</div>
```

.ts

```
export class EntityImage {
  url: string;
}

images$: Observable<EntityImage[]>;

getImages(entity: Entity, format: ImageFormatType): EntityImage[] {
    if (!entity) return [];

    return (entity.images || []).map(img => {
      img.url = this.getImageURL(entity.uid, format, img.uid);
      return img;
    });
  }

  getImageURL(entityUid: string, format: ImageFormatType, imageUid?: string, imageCache?: number): string {
    const path = Entity.getImagePath(entityUid, format, imageUid);
    const url = this.firebaseProvider.getUrl(path);

    return imageCache ? `${url}&imageCache=${imageCache}` : url;
  }

  selectEntity(matEvent: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
    this.entity$ = matEvent.option.value;
    // ERROR here
    this.images$ = this.getImages(matEvent.option.value, 'ORIGINAL');
  }
```

Is there a way to do it without having the error above?

Comment: what do you mean with `direct updates`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [of](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/of.html) operator to do that.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

images$: Observable<EntityImage[]>;

getImages(entity: Entity, format: ImageFormatType): Observable<EntityImage[]> {
    if (!entity) return [];

    return (entity.images || []).map(img => {
      img.url = this.getImageURL(entity.uid, format, img.uid);
      return of(img);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Is there a way I can do it without having to change the `getImages()` and `getImagesURL()` function? Like having the of() in `selectEntity()`

Comment: You cant because you want to return Observable by define `images$: Observable<EntityImage[]>;`

Comment: I did change the function `getImages()` to your post but I get the following error: `Type 'Observable<EntityImage>[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<EntityImage[]>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 5 more.ts(2740)`

Comment: can you share your conde in stackblitz so i can take a look at?

Answer (score 0):

You can just change `selectEntity` to this:

```
selectEntity(matEvent: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
    this.entity$ = matEvent.option.value;
    // ERROR here solved
    this.images$ = of(this.getImages(matEvent.option.value, 'ORIGINAL'));
  }
```

Comment: The page doesn't automatically refresh the images when I submit another one or remove one though

Comment: Of course. You should post how are you adding/removing them.